# Criticalcss on initial build with webpack fails

Tags: javascript, webpack, critical-css

So I'm using Webpack to bundle up my js and css.

I've added the Webpack-plugin-critical to output an external css file featuring critical styles. This file gets added to my (twig) template.

It works fine if I run Webpack a second time, though the **initial** build fails and I get an error saying it can't find the primary generated css file. How do I expose the primary css file output from ExtractTextPlugin to Webpack-plugin-critical allowing it to consume the file and produce a critical css file on initial build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one stuck on this. Use this plugin; https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-critical-webpack-plugin

It builds the critical styles AFTER the sass has been compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible.

https://github.com/nrwl/webpack-plugin-critical/blob/master/src/critical.ts#L129

You can see that webpack-plugin-critical use the event hook "emit" which assets files are not generated by webpack compiler yet.

In the other hand, I recommend that you could use an other independent webpack config for generate critical css specifically.